# How to add a tag when sending an email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailgun

I'm using the mailgun-ruby gem and I can't seem to figure out how to add a tag to the outgoing email.

```
def send(params, tag = nil)
  mg = Mailgun::Client.new("...")
  mg.add_tag(tag) unless tag.nil?
  mg.send_message my_domain, params
end
```

The add_tag method is undefined.  I'm looking at the source and I see there is add_tag but it is on some message_builder class.  How is it exposed to the Client class that I am using?

https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby/blob/master/lib/mailgun/messages/message_builder.rb#L160

Answer (score 2):

Use an instance of `MessageBuilder` to prepare your message as described in [mailgun-ruby docs](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby/blob/master/MessageBuilder.md).

```
def send(params, tag = nil)
  mg_client = Mailgun::Client.new("your-api-key")
  mb_obj = Mailgun::MessageBuilder.new()

  # ...set some settings on mb_obj, probably from params as well...

  mb_obj.add_tag(tag) unless tag.nil?

  mg_client.send_message(my_domain, mb_obj)
end
```

Also, it's probably best to separate `Mailgun::Client` initialization and message sending code.